# Search results difference between root site and Subsite

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, search-results, root

Good Day,
I have a question about SharePoint search results.

I have the root Site and the Subsite. On the Subsite I have the List with 11086 elements. Every element has a field with “order” value.

When I wrote “order” in search field on the Subsite, I got 11086 elements on search results page.
When I wrote “order” in search field on the root site, I got 6000 elements on search results page.

I was searching for the reason of this difference in search results on root site and subsite.

I used manually request crawling and re-indexing of site, Subsite and Subsite List.Now I get 7679 elements on root site after search by word “order” and 9391 elements on Subsite…

I created the Search Center Site. It returns 7679 elements like the root site.
I can’t understand this search results difference and would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely it is "trim duplicates" that is the reason.
As the trim duplicates algoritm often will wrong when dealing with very similar items you could try to disabled it, http://www.sharepointsearch.net/disable-duplicate-removal-in-sharepoint-search/

In general I would recommend that almost any Search related question should be answered with "what does the SharePoint Search Query Tool say ? " ;-)
https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Tools/tree/master/Solutions/SharePoint.Search.QueryTool

Comment: +1 Thank you very much. You are absolutely right. https://blogs.perficient.com/2013/04/18/sharepoint-2013-search-not-display-all-results/